# NVMe on old HP Proliant DL380 G6

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, nvme

Do NVMe drives work on HP Proliant DL380 G6 boards?
These servers have:

```
1 x PCIe Gen2 X8 Full Length, Full Height Slot
2 x PCIe Gen2 X4 Half Length, Full Height Slot
```

Is there any interference with disk controllers?

Comment: Imagine a Ferrari on bicycle wheels, stuck in traffic - that....just don't please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they work.

It depends on what NVMe card you use, but you'll be capped to PCIe 2.0 speeds in terms of throughput.

What's the goal of the project?

Comment: The goal is to buy some computer for work (instead of the given laptop) to process lots of data with a programming language that makes parallelization easy - Clojure.  Although the RAM is only DDR3 at a no so fast speed, I'm thinking of being able to process everything in RAM (64GB maybe) instead of using SQL on a remote server.  And the NVMe can be used to have fast I/O when necessary (loading JVM, for ex) with a quiet workspace.  I think this will suit me well at a very reasonable price.  What would be the cap for PCIe 2.0 in the X4 and X8 slots? 4GB/s and 2GB/s?

Comment: 2 Gigabytes/second.

Comment: 2GB/s seems very fast to me.  Thanks.